# Moodle's database synchronization w external database

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, moodle

My company, a big university of sorts, has planned to synchronize the external database records (SQL Server) - mainly user ( students) records and courses records with moodle database ( PostgreSQL), that is used for remote learning.

So far the synchronization works by Cron (every hour and every night), my company wants to make it automatic, with no Cron.

Since I am a beginner in such matter I am struggling firstly to plan the whole process.

First clue concerning the synchronization I found, is that I should try understanding the web services and external services API.
I've learnt little how such API can be built, how  webservices API in installed in moodle. Still I don't know where to go with that knowledge.

I have little to none idea where to start planning the process.

If you guys have any clue, on what I should do, any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check out Debezium or SymmetricDS

Comment: Interesting propositions, but I am afraid the very thing circles around building a certain API, nonetheless I'll propose these solutions, thanks !